# exit status in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am running a application form the shell script. Now I like to know the exit status of the application to know whether it exit normally or abnormally ( crash etc). How I know it?
Example:
./mytestApp

Comment: how is the question significantly different from your other post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451297/exit-code-when-crashed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` contains the exit status of the last command executed. So, if the last command was `./mytestapp`, `$?` would contain its exit status immediately after (note that you can only retrieve this value once and it must be retrieved immediately after the command whose exit status you want to know). You may want to capture it in a variable, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
./mytestapp
APPSUCCESS=$?
# Continue doing whatever it is you're doing
```

This all assumes that you're using bash (sh and zsh will work as well, IIRC).

Answer (score 3):

Bash stores the last process' exit value in the special variable `$?`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use special variable `$?` which contains an exit status of the last comand.

Answer (score 0):

The special variable `$?` will contain the exit status of the last command in bash.